# Find the ratio in which edges are divided in a tetrahedron

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, solid-geometry

In a regular tetrahedron, E and F are the midpoints of edges AD and BC, respectively.
M and N are on segments CD and EF, respectively,  such that α=∠MNC=π/4, β=∠NME=π/3. 
In which ratio are EF and CD divided by M and N, respectively?

Taking D as origin:
$$
\overrightarrow{DA} = \overrightarrow{a}\\ \overrightarrow{DB} = \overrightarrow{b}\\
\overrightarrow{DC} = \overrightarrow{c}\\ \overrightarrow{DE} = \frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow{a}\\
\overrightarrow{DF} = \frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow{b+c}
$$ 
I don't know how to continue, if you have an easier and more elegant way to do it, don't hesitate showing it, using vector methods.

Comment: Set: $\overrightarrow{DN}=\alpha\overrightarrow{DE}+(1-\alpha)\overrightarrow{DF}$ and $\overrightarrow{DM}=\beta\overrightarrow{DC}$, and use the given conditions to find two equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.